# What is the origin of Russian барин ['bа:rʲin]?

Tags: etymology, indo-european, slavic-languages, celtic

The word (pl. ***баре,*** ['bа:rʲe]) is roughly rendered into English as 'gentry' meaning 'a noble person without a position at imperial court'. The *boyar* is possibly not a cognate.

What surprises me the most is that the word ***bár*** in Old Irish (especially in its poetic speech, or in *bérla na filed*) had meant *´a wise chief'*, while the most ancient Irish sources provide a word for ´***bárnía***', or *´wise warrior´*, and this word is even more resemblant to the Russian ***´barin´***.

The word барон 'baron' is not a possible source, because it does not coincide with the plural form (***бароны <=барон*** VS ***барин => баре***). However, the plural of ***боярин*** is *бояре*, which suggests a pattern, but does not explain the intervocal [j] in  *boyar*. What is the etymology of ***boyar***, by the way?

Hence, the question is: are there any reliable etymologucal sources (please do not quote any Vasmer or the like) which might help me in shedding some light on this issue?

Comment: Also compare this one: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=baron

Comment: @Anixx - Also consider the Romani (Gypsy) word `baró` which means "chief". :D

Comment: What's wrong with Vasmer?

Comment: Can you define "reliable etymological sources", considering that Vasmer "or the like" doesn't match that definition?

Comment: A reliable etymological source is a source that gives a historically reasonable explanations. E.g. the tracing Russian 'barin' back to 'baron' is not reliable, because it does not establish the initial form. The Romani word is not reliable, either, because it does not establish the first form, from which that word came into the Romani languages, etc.

Comment: @Alex B Vasmer has a poor scientific intuition, especially when it comes to the cross-linguistics.

Comment: Just for the record, the author of the famous Russian etymological dictionary was Max Julius Friedrich Vasmer. Who is Alex B Vasmer?

Comment: Have you seen the @?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. My linguistic knowledge does not encompass text speak, unfortunately.

Comment: "What's wrong with Vasmer?  – Alex B." - the frequent lack of historical sources on which he relied.

Answer (score 1):

The contact of Slavs with the Celtic people was very long ago, in the 4th - 2nd centuries BC, in the times when the Proto-Slavic language still existed, the few Slavic words that can be explained by that contact were borrowed into the Ptoto-Slavic. Because of this, it looks quite improbable that the long Celtic `á` of **bár** would give the Slavic `o` of `болꙗринъ` which was a short vowel in those times. `Болꙗринъ` is the original form of `барин` since the latter was attested much later. Besides, Slavs didn't have aristocracy BC, so the word couldn't appear that early.

All the attempts to explain that word by Celtic influence break against the laws of phonetics.

Comment: All the attempts to explain this word by Turkic influence (which Vasmer did) break against the laws of common sense: he suggests bai as an initial form, then it becomes Bulgaric, then the l changes into j...

Comment: Another issue is whether it is correct to call this a "contacts", when the Slavs of this period are generally unknown to us, and who are the abstract "Proto-Slavs" of the 4th - 2nd centuries BC in their, probably, different origins.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue for the possible connection with word "baron" actually.

The word "baron" itself comes from Old French, which at the time preserved still some forms of declension and "baron" was the accusative/object/indirect case, while nominative/subject/direct was "**ber**", which itself had Germanic/Frankish origin in **baro** ("freeman").